# Task switching using a queue 

Tags: gcc, x86, scheduling, multitasking, osdev

i'm developing my own hobby os, and now i'm stuck with a problem on the scheduler/task switching.

I planned to use a FIFO queue as structure to hold processes. I implemented it using linked list.

I also decided to use the iret method to switch from a task to another (so when the os was serving an interrupt request just before the iret i change the ESP register in order to move to the new task).

But i have a problem. 
When the os start it launch two tasks:

- idle
- shell

And with these two i have no problem.
But if i try to launch two other tasks (with a simply printf inside), the task queue was corrupted.

If after that i try to print the queue it print only two tasks that are the 2 just created and with idle and shell disappeared, but the os continues to work (i think that in a specific moment the esp field of the new tasks was replaced with the esp content of the shell).

The task data structure is:

```
typedef struct task_t{
    pid_t pid;  
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    void (*start_function)();
    task_state status;
    task_register_t *registers;
    unsigned int cur_quants;
    unsigned int eip;
    long int esp;
    unsigned int pdir;
    unsigned int ptable;
    struct task_t *next;
}task_t;
```

and the tss is:

```
typedef struct {    
        unsigned int edi;   //+0
        unsigned int esi;   //+1
        unsigned int ebp;  //+2
        unsigned int esp;  //+3 (can be null)
        unsigned int ebx;  //+4
        unsigned int edx;  //+5
        unsigned int ecx;  //+6
        unsigned int eax;  //+7       
        unsigned int eip;  //+8
        unsigned int cs;   //+9
        unsigned int eflags;  //+10
        unsigned int end;           
} task_register_t;
```

The scheduler function is the following:

```
void schedule(unsigned int *stack){
    asm("cli");
    if(active == TRUE){
      task_t* cur_task = dequeue_task();      
      if(cur_task != NULL){
        cur_pid = cur_task->pid;
        dbg_bochs_print("@@@@@@@");
        dbg_bochs_print(cur_task->name);
        if(cur_task->status!=NEW){
          cur_task->esp=*stack;
        } else {
          cur_task->status=READY;         
          ((task_register_t *)(cur_task->esp))->eip = cur_task->eip;                  
        }
        enqueue_task(cur_task->pid, cur_task);
        cur_task=get_task();
        if(cur_task->status==NEW){
          cur_task->status=READY;
        }
        dbg_bochs_print(" -- ");
        dbg_bochs_print(cur_task->name);
        dbg_bochs_print("\n");        
        //load_pdbr(cur_taskp->pdir);
        *stack = cur_task->esp;
      } else {
        enqueue_task(cur_task->pid, cur_task);
      }
    }
    active = FALSE;
    return;
    asm("sti");
}
```

The tss is initalized with the following values:

```
void new_tss(task_register_t* tss, void (*func)()){
    tss->eax=0;    
    tss->ebx=0;
    tss->ecx=0;
    tss->edx=0;
    tss->edi =0;
    tss->esi =0;
    tss->cs = 8;
    tss->eip = (unsigned)func;
    tss->eflags = 0x202;
    tss->end = (unsigned) suicide;
    //tss->fine = (unsigned)end; //per metterci il suicide  
    return;
}
```

And the function that creates a new task is the following:

```
pid_t new_task(char *task_name, void (*start_function)()){
    asm("cli"); 
    task_t *new_task;
    table_address_t local_table;
    unsigned int new_pid = request_pid();   
    new_task = (task_t*)kmalloc(sizeof(task_t));    
    strcpy(new_task->name, task_name);
    new_task->next = NULL;
    new_task->start_function = start_function;
    new_task->cur_quants=0;
    new_task->pid = new_pid;
    new_task->eip = (unsigned int)start_function;
    new_task->esp = (unsigned int)kmalloc(STACK_SIZE) + STACK_SIZE-100;
    new_task->status = NEW;
    new_task->registers = (task_register_t*)new_task->esp;
    new_tss(new_task->registers, start_function);
    local_table = map_kernel();
    new_task->pdir = local_table.page_dir;
    new_task->ptable = local_table.page_table;
    //new_task->pdir = 0;
    //new_task->ptable = 0;
    enqueue_task(new_task->pid, new_task);
    //(task_list.current)->cur_quants = MAX_TICKS;          
    asm("sti");
    return new_pid;
}
```

I'm sure that i just forgot something, or i miss some consideration. But i cannot figure what i'm missing.

Actually i'm working only in kernel mode, and inside the same address space (pagiing is enabled, but actually i use the same pagedir for all tasks).

The ISR macros are defined here: 
https://github.com/inuyasha82/DreamOs/blob/master/include/processore/handlers.h

I declared four kinds of function in order to handle ISR:

1. EXCEPTION
2. EXCEPTION_EC (an exception with an error code)
3. IRQ
4. SYSCALL

Obviously the scheduler is called by an IRQ routine, so the macro looks like:

```
__asm__("INT_"#n":"\
        "pushad;" \
        "movl %esp, %eax;"\
    "pushl %eax;"\
        "call _irqinterrupt;"\
        "popl %eax;"\
        "movl %eax, %esp;"\
        "popad;"\
        "iret;")
```

the irq handler function is:

```
void _irqinterrupt(unsigned int esp){
    asm("cli;");
    int irqn;
    irqn = get_current_irq();  
    IRQ_s* tmpHandler; 
    if(irqn>=0) {               
        tmpHandler = shareHandler[irqn];        
        if(tmpHandler!=0) {
            tmpHandler->IRQ_func();         
            #ifdef DEBUG
                printf("2 - IRQ_func: %d, %d\n", tmpHandler->IRQ_func, tmpHandler);
            #endif
            while(tmpHandler->next!=NULL) {
                tmpHandler = tmpHandler->next;                           
                #ifdef DEBUG
                    printf("1 - IRQ_func (_prova): %d, %d\n", tmpHandler->IRQ_func, tmpHandler);
                #endif
                if(tmpHandler!=0) tmpHandler->IRQ_func();
            }
      } else printf("irqn: %d\n", irqn);
    }
    else printf("IRQ N: %d E' arrivato qualcosa che non so gestire ", irqn);
    if(irqn<=8 && irqn!=2) outportb(MASTER_PORT, EOI);
    else if(irqn<=16 || irqn==2){     
      outportb(SLAVE_PORT, EOI);
      outportb(MASTER_PORT, EOI);
    }

    schedule(&esp);
    asm("sti;");
    return;
}
```

And these are the enqueue_task and dequeue_task functions:

```
void enqueue_task(pid_t pid, task_t* n_task){
  n_task->next=NULL;
  if(task_list.tail == NULL){
    task_list.head = n_task;
    task_list.tail = task_list.head;    
  } else {
    task_list.head->next=n_task;    
    task_list.head = n_task;    
  }
}

task_t* dequeue_task(){
    if(task_list.head==NULL){
      return NULL;
    } else {
      task_t* _task;
      _task = task_list.tail; 
      task_list.tail=_task->next;
      return _task;
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance, 
and let me know if you need more details!

Comment: Please try to have a strict naming/parameter passing convention for all your functions, so that if later this project gets big and becomes the next linux, it wouldn't become as messy as that!

Comment: Also, are you booting your OS in a [freestanding environment](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/preface/hosted_and_free_standing.html)? If so, you don't have access to the standard libraries (you have to write your own)

Comment: Yeah i'm writing my own libraries i know. The os is written from scratch, so it is running on a freestanding environment :).

Comment: So you have already implemented `printf`? In that case, are you sure there is no bug in `printf` itself?

Comment: Yeah i already implemented printf. I think that the printf is working quite well. Not sure that is 100% bug free, but quite confident that it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried not using `printf` in your threads and see if they still corrupt the queue? (this is probably not the error, but worth checking anyway)

Comment: didn't think about that! I'll try it later when i go back at home. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, i just tried to remove the printfs from the threads, but i still have the same problem. Any other idea? I'm stuck here.

Comment: I think you can get more answers on http://forum.osdev.org/.

Comment: It's a bit too much code to go through and yet not all possibly relevant code is presented. I can see immediately one thing that's not quite right. You never make sure that the segment register values are correct (`DS`, `ES`, `SS`) for your ISR code, you don't set them to known good values in the beginning of the ISR (and you don't restore them afterwards). And you continue running with whatever `EFLAGS` you've got. But how about `EFLAGS.DF`? String instructions depend on it and they are often used as part of things like `memset()`, `memcpy()`, `memmove()`. And they can change `EFLAGS.DF` too.

Comment: It's also odd to see `asm("sti");` **AFTER** `return;`.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell. How does your assembly part of the isr look like? What makes me think is the problem (since you can save and restore two tasks but not more) is that you don't push and pop all registers properly. You do use pusha and popa for the isr right?

I also want to add that having cli and sti like you have done there can be dangerous. In your isrs set cli as the first opcode. Then you wont need to use sti at all because iret will automatically flip this on for you (it is actually a bit in the eflags register).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer origamicoder, check my edits with the answers to your questions.